# Launch Android Default Email application through btn click

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I posted this query here, but as usual, noone knows / no replies

http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=41513#41513

How can I launch the android default mail application through the click of a button in my code?

I would also like to know, how this can be done to launch the contacts list also.

Any help in this regard is appreciated,

Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 1):

How can I launch the android default mail application through the click of a button in my code?

Use an [`ACTION_SEND` `Intent`](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/11/02/a-call-to-action-action_send-that-is/).

(BTW, I apologize for the formatting of that blog post -- AndroidGuys keeps changing hosting providers, which screws up my posts)

I would also like to know, how this can be done to launch the contacts list also.

Use an [`ACTION_PICK` `Intent`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation/RotationOne/).